# Keyboard shortcut for switching panes in tmux in iTerm2 on OS X

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I have tmux installed with iTerm2 on OS X.

While I can do `Cmd+left/right` to switch between tabs, I cannot seem to be able to switch between panes under the same tab using `Ctl+b o` (that is, `Control` and `b` together, followed by an `o`?) as suggested by others.

I don't think I've touched any default key binding for tmux, so what is the correct keyboard shortcut for this operation?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>Opt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can see a list of all your bindings using `Ctl+b ?`. You're looking for the following line:

```
bind-key          o select-pane -t :.+
```

although it sounds as if you may have a key other than 'o' bound to it.

Comment: Ctl+b doesn't invoke tmux commands in iterm2, at least not mine.

Comment: Control-b is the default prefix in `tmux`, unless you change it in your configuration. I don't know exactly how iTerm 2's `tmux` integration works, having never really felt better than just using `tmux` directly.